# wget error "Converting links in "url" Incomplete or invalid multibyte sequence encountered"

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, wget, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to help a colleague on a Macbook Air MacOsx 10.11.06 with archiving a website using wget (version 1.19.1) installed through brew.
Using this command.

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domain scart.be --warc-file=20161103_scart www.scart.be
```

However this results in an error in the terminal:

> Converting links in http://www.scart.be/index.html?q=fr%2Fnode%2F1135.html 35-27
>   Incomplete or invalid multibyte sequence encountered

I tested it and it works fine on a Ubuntu xenial machine (wget version 1.17.1) and on another system, MacOsx 10.11.06. (wget version 1.19.1)

I have tried changing the "--restrict-file-names=windows" to "--restrict-file-names=nocontrol", nothing changed. If we try to import the .warc file into Webrecorder-player it displays "no bookmarks found" where it works with .warc files created on two other machines mentioned previously.
What I have found so far on other sites, is that this error is related to character encoding and have been stuck there.

Comment: You may need first to find the exact webpage that create the problem, to see inside of it if some characters has invalid encodings. Also does your problem repeat itself multiple times? Otherwise it could be a transient network problem or even an issue of not enough space locally to download everything?